# How do I determine which direction a current is travelling in a wire when it has two junctions?

Tags: electric-circuits

[image]

For example in this circuit image, assuming the (DC) current starts from the battery and goes up, it then diverges at one junction and according to this junction, the current travels down the middle wire. But at the bottom junction, the current enters from the right and appears to go up the middle wire? So I ended up with a contradiction. How can the direction of the current be determined in a case like this?
and does this complicate kcl in any way

thanks

Comment: In general you need to know the resistances in the branches. Even in a shorted diagram like this one (no purposeful loads), the wires have small but non-zero resistances.

Comment: thanks for the response but how is this relevant

Comment: The way to determine the direction of the current is by using Kirchoff's loop rules and Ohm's law. To use Ohm's law, you need known resistances and voltages to solve for currents. You have not provided any known resistances, so we are left guessing what will happen here.

Comment: The **idealized** version of this diagram is physically impossible, as you are applying a finite voltage to a loop with zero resistance. That would give infinite current, which is not physically possible. This is what is called a short circuit. In real life, the wires would have (as stated above) some small but non-zero resistance, leading to extremely high currents, and fire or melting wires.

Comment: If you can provide an example with some given resistances, I will be happy to post an answer :)

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer $$V=IR$$ $$\frac{V}{R} = I$$ When R=0, I is undefined, not infinite. This "error" only occurs using ohms law, which is a steady state solution to the drude model of conductivity, which should read "the potential  needed to maintain a constant current". In the case these wires have no resistance, the current can never be constant hence the undefined value. Unless ofcourse during the transient stage of the drude model, the potential is turned off, which is not the case here. V=IR doesn't work here, as there is no steady state.If current was undefined for zero resistances

Comment: Then no one could model superconductors, which is obviously not the case. Other common misconceptions with ohms law, is that the potential across a zero resistance wire is zero, which is obviously false.

Comment: @jensenpaull, when OP is asking questions about applying Kirchhoff's laws to a simple loop, I'm not sure introducing non-Ohmic behaviour will make understanding any easier.

Comment: Perhaps, but what you have stated is completely wrong. Which warranted an explanation.

Comment: Using ordinary metal wires, don't you observe Ohmic inverse proportionality between R and I for fixed V when R becomes very small? Until the wire melts, as stated on my post. There is nothing in OPs diagram that tells us that superconductors are relevant here.

Comment: Mathematically ohms law doesn't make sense when r=0, for a non zero potential. In every way that you look at this problem, for R=0, the current is not infinite. Like you have stated, OP's diagrams does not include resistance, zero resistance wires ARE super conductors, and the  current in superconductors is  not infinite, as you have suggested. Look up the derivation of ohms law from the drude model, and you will understand why it doesn't make sense for ohms law to be applied here, real wires do not have zero resistance and ohms law can be applied as r≠ 0

Comment: For a quick rundown, ohms law is derived in the steady state where the acceleration of an electron is zero $\vec{a} = 0$. Aka- current is constant. When r=0, the is no constant current for a non zero potential. The equation doesn't make sense in this   context as there is no "steady state", and hence ohms law gives I=undefined, as no constant can current exist.

Comment: What I wrote was that "The idealized version of this diagram is physically impossible, as you are applying a finite voltage to a loop with zero resistance. That would give infinite current, which is not physically possible". As the whole question is given a Ohmic context, my statement was meant to be interpreted in that context. In every way you look at this statement, the part "That would give infinite current, which is not physically possible" should make it clear I don't believe infinite current exists, superconductor or not.

Comment: Finally, the reference to Kirchhoff's laws in the OP implies we are using the [lumped-element model](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumped-element_model) which does not hold for superconductors to begin with. But you know this from studying the Drude model, I am sure ;)

Comment: I took your statement about infinite(actually undefined) currents being impossible, and then say 'real wires have non zero resistance' to be the   'resolution' to the problem you have posed (which isn't the resolution). In anycase,  if you agree that even in exactly zero resistance wires, the current isn't infinite, then we are in agreement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not withstanding the need for resistances in the circuit, conventional current flows from high  potential (positive battery terminal) to low potential (negative battery terminal). Showing the direction of the currents leaving the bottom node towards the top node would be the mechanical equivalent of water flowing up hill.

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1. The current flow is from the top node to the bottom node through both the right-hand and central wires, due to the potential difference between the two nodes.  The proportions between the two wires depend on their resistances, but the signs do not

Comment: thanks so much. So to determine the direction of current flow in a wire, I just need to consider the node/junctions of this wire and determine which has the higher Potential and which has the lower potential?

Comment: In theory yes, but remember the field isn't just the batteries field, surface charge fields are important

Comment: @MaalikSerebryakov Your circuit is simple because with only one voltage source  it's easy to see that the direction of the currents in the center and right conductor have to go into the   bottom node and the direction of the current going out of the bottom node has to go to the negative battery terminal. But with multiple voltage sources and branches it may not be so obvious.

Comment: However,  if you properly conduct node analysis using KCL you can assume any directions of the currents. If, on doing the analysis, you get a negative value for a current it simply means its actual direction is opposite to that you chose.

Comment: @Bob D, Thanks again. Can I just assume current directions for the standard application of KVL too? (not node analysis).

Comment: @MaalikSerebryakov Absolutely yes. It is actually easier to to it for loop current analysis with KVL than node voltage analysis with KCL. That's because with the latter you  need to determine node voltages first from which you can determine node currents.

Answer (score 0):

When you do this jobs, you have to choose a convention to the sign for each wire. Then you apply the Kirchhoff's laws (nodes and loops) and the characterics law of every element of the circuit (like Ohm law for the resistor). Everything is applied with sign due to the convention you chose above. If it was "correct" your guess of direction, you have that the current in the wire is + some amperes, if it was not, you have the opposite sign.

Comment: I already made an initial guess ( that the current starts from the battery and goes up) but my question is when you apply kcl to both junctions, you get contradictory current directions. What should be done then

Comment: @MaalikSerebryakov, kcl only tells you that the sum of "incoming" currents is equal to the sum of "outgoing" currents, but you are free to choose what wires you consider incoming and outgoing, so long as you do it consistently. So you need to change one of the two arrows in your vertical middle branch. Ohm's laws might later tell you that some of your currents are negative: that means that the current flows in the opposite direction to what you "guessed" when you placed the arrow.

Comment: thanks this is more helpful. but now my question is, how do I make sure I am applying KCL Consistently? in this diagramme for example. In the manner I applied KCL, I arrived at a contradiction in the direction of current flow in the middle wire. What should I have done instead?

Comment: The current is the same everywhere in a wire, so once you have assigned an "arrow" to a wire, e.g the arrow pointing down from the top in your diagram, then the current must flow in that direction all the way throughout the wire, hence into the bottom junction.

Comment: The mistake you are making in the picture is that you are taking two different direction for the current in the middle wire. Just choose one of them, either exiting from the upper node (and so forced to enter in the lower node) or exiting from the lower node (and so forced to enter in the upper node)

Comment: @emanuele So in these cases its okay to just pick any direction and it doesn't matter? Then Can I just randomly pick any directions for the current in any wire? I have a feeling KCL wont work in that case

Comment: Yes, just pick a convention and keep it until the end. If the sign you obtain is when you put number inside is plus, so you have guessed correctly the direction, otherwise the direction was opposite. Think about this: if you have a very hard circuit, with hundreds of batteries, resistors, how can you know "a priori" the direction of every current in the circuit? There is just no way to know before, because it depends on the relative power of the batteries, in a way that you can't foresee. So the advice is the one I gave you before

Comment: And, to be correct, you have put too many arrows in your circuit for the current. In each wire the current can flow just in one direction (that you don't know which but you make a guess as said). In the picture you wrote 6 arrows, but you have 3 wires, so you just need 3 arrows, one per wire.